# How to enforce cousin dependencies on purpose in c# using NuGet

Tags: c#, dependencies, nuget, blazor

I am designing a C# program with sub modules (Blazor server-side and RCLs/Plugins) and need to implement the following:

[image]

Reason being that "Package A" could live for some time and must reference v.1.0 of "Package B" (an update might come in x months for Package A so its not touched), while "Package C" can get newer versions of "Package B" more often.
I cannot live with conflicts in this setup or "Nearest Wins" - I need to strictly load all assemblies as they are referenced by Package A and C each in isolation in the same main assembly.

Maybe I dont understand the NuGet concepts quite well, so please tell me how I can make it work?